# Tracking techniques used by internet advertisers

Tags: tracking, ads

I know it looks like I haven't done my research but... I don't seem to be able to find any reliable papers/websites explaining ***in detail*** the tracking techniques used by the internet advertisers. (and believe me, I've been looking for good sources for 5 months now). Has anyone done any similar research / project in the past? Can you suggest any reading?

Just in case if my post is not clear, this was one of many questions i had:
[How Do Internet Advertisers Use Third-Party Cookies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8794981/how-do-internet-advertisers-use-third-party-cookies)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This is a programming related question and answer site, and as your question has nothing to do with programming, it is off-topic here. Please take a few minutes to read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) so you'll know what questions are (and are not) appropriate to ask here. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few research studies:

- [Persistent Cookies](http://threatpost.com/en_us/blogs/html5-being-used-set-persistent-cookies-study-finds-080111)
- [Folly of Detecting Tracking from Cookies](http://www.thesecuritypractice.com/the_security_practice/2011/08/the-folly-of-detecting-tracking-from-cookies.html)